# Docker MultiStage Build Exposing web app, and running bash commands

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I have this dockerfile. I am attempting to create an image that has ubuntu and a website contained within. The ubuntu commands open firefox and should navigate to the url that has the website. The `CMD` portion works as expected but `http:localhost:8080` does not work as intended. Here is the dockerfile and I will walk you through each section.

> Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SecondApp.dll"]

#ubuntu 16.04
FROM ubuntu:16.04
#set the working directory. All commands will be ran here
WORKDIR /root/
#Update packages, and install sudo
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo
#not sure what all this does, but it gets the gui and firefox working
RUN export uid=1000 gid=1000 && \
    mkdir -p /home/developer && \
    echo "developer:x:${uid}:${gid}:Developer,,,:/home/developer:/bin/bash" >> /etc/passwd && \
    echo "developer:x:${uid}:" >> /etc/group && \
    echo "developer ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/developer && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/developer && \
    chown ${uid}:${gid} -R /home/developer
#install firefox, wget and add chrome to sources
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y firefox
RUN apt-get install wget -y
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
RUN apt-get update
#install severel dependent packages for firefox and chrome
RUN apt-get install google-chrome-stable dbus-x11 packagekit-gtk3-module libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module -y
#xdotool is used for mimicking key presses 
RUN apt-get install xdotool -y
#not sure what this does either
RUN chown -R developer:developer /home/developer
RUN mkdir /var/run/dbus/
#? user
USER developer
ENV HOME /home/developer
#not sure what dbus-daemon does, but this does open up firefox, navigate to localhost:8080, and full screens the app. To keep the container running bin/bash is ran after, it remains in the background successfully.
CMD sudo dbus-daemon --system --fork && /usr/bin/firefox -url http://localhost:8080 & xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --class "Firefox" windowactivate key F11  & /bin/bash
```

> SecondApp

SecondApp is just the default created app for visual studio 2017 for an asp.net core web application. no MVC, nothing added. When debugging. Navigating to `http:localhost:56545` will bring up the home page.

So from the above build of the dockerfile. Using this docker run command

`docker run -ti --rm -p 8080:80 -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix repo/repo`

or this one

`docker run -ti --rm -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix repo/repo`

Will run the container, open Firefox at url `localhost:8080`, and fullscreen firefox. But, `localhost:8080` cannot be found.

Is there something wrong with the ports/networking that I am missing?